# Нужно вывести имена, но выходит хрень. Такое безобразие наверное изза того, что вывожу целый объект, а не имя. Но как это сделать правильно?

Tags: java

```
package com.company;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person1 = new Person();
        Person person2 = new Person();
        Person person3 = new Person();
        Person[] arr = {person1,person2,person3};

        person1.name = "Bob";
        person2.name = "Robert";
        person3.name = "Nick";

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Обращаемся непосредственно к полю объекта
`System.out.println(arr[i].name);`

Comment: спасибо друг. Никак не мог уловить